# DataDog Monitor alert notification are not send to Distribution lists

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

I am unable to recieve alerts on the distribution channel from datadog monitors

i have tried on two different distribution channel list but unable to recieve any alerts from datadog moniotors apart form this when i send email to individual account i am recieving alers.